# How to launch specific screen on tap of local notification in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, uilocalnotification, react-native-push-notification

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library in react-native to schedule local notification, when i tap of notification either from notification centre or from top of the app, i want to redirect the user to specific screen. Currently react-native-push-notification lib using old **UILocalNotification** classes which are already deprecated.

Below is my code to configure local notification.

**onNotification** is a callback method triggers when user launches the app from notification centre for iOS and similarly **onAction** is for Android.

```
/**
 * To configure for local notifications
*/
 export function localNotificationConfigure() {
   PushNotification.configure({
   onNotification: async function (notification) {
     console.log('notification.data', notification.userInteraction);
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
   },
  onAction: async function (notification) {
    console.log('notification', notification.userInteraction);
   },
  permissions: {
   alert: true,
   badge: true,
   sound: true,
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
   requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',
  });
 }
```

Is there any way that i can achieve this. Is it because of lib using UILocalNotification which is deprecated and i'm not able to get the action back in the code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://product.farewell.io/visible-react-native-push-notifications-that-work-on-both-ios-and-android-5e90badb4a0f) helped me in achieving my desired functionality.